# Full text search on Neo4j over rich text with html markup

Tags: lucene, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In my Neo4j application I have a `Product` entity with a `name` and `description` fields. Both of these fields are used in legacy indexing over Lucene.

`Product.name` is a simple text and there are no issues here but `Product.description` can contain HTML markup and elements.

Right now for my index I use `StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36)`. What analyzer should I use in order to skip all HTML elements ?

How to tell Neo4J Lucene index to not use any HTML elements in Product.description ? I'd like to index only words.

**UPDATED:**

I have found following class `HTMLStripCharFilter` and reimplemented my Analyzer as following:

```
public final class StandardAnalyzerV36 extends Analyzer {

    private Analyzer analyzer;

    public StandardAnalyzerV36() {
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    }

    public StandardAnalyzerV36(Set<?> stopWords) {
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, stopWords);
    }

    @Override
    public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        return analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, new HTMLStripCharFilter(CharReader.get(reader)));
    }

    @Override
    public final TokenStream reusableTokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) throws IOException {
        return analyzer.reusableTokenStream(fieldName, reader);
    }

}
```

also I have added a new maven dependecy to my Neo4j project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works fine right now, but I'm not sure that the method

```
  @Override
    public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        return analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, new HTMLStripCharFilter(CharReader.get(reader)));
    }
```

is a proper place for `HTMLStripCharFilter` initialization.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added following init method:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = template.getGraphDatabaseService();
        try (Transaction t = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            Index<Node> autoIndex = graphDb.index().forNodes("node_auto_index");
            graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "type", "fulltext");
            graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "to_lower_case", "true");
            graphDb.index().setConfiguration(autoIndex, "analyzer", StandardAnalyzerV36.class.getName());
            t.success();
        }
    }
```

and created following class:

```
public final class StandardAnalyzerV36 extends Analyzer {

    private Analyzer analyzer;

    public StandardAnalyzerV36() {
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
    }

    public StandardAnalyzerV36(Set<?> stopWords) {
        analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, stopWords);
    }

    @Override
    public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        return analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, new HTMLStripCharFilter(CharReader.get(reader)));
    }

    @Override
    public final TokenStream reusableTokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) throws IOException {
        return analyzer.reusableTokenStream(fieldName, reader);
    }

}
```

Now everything works as expected. Hope it will help someone else. Good luck.